# Searching a JSON Object regarding Speed/Efficiency

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, search, object

I have a question on how objects/arrays are searched. Take the following for example:

```
while ($obj = $sql->fetch_object()) {
    array_push($jsonObj,array('serial' => $obj->serialNum,'model' => $obj->model,'os' => $obj->os,'man' => $obj->manufacturer,'team' => $obj->team,'enabled'=>'true'));

if($.inArray((JsonObj[i].os)) >= 0){...}
```

I basically have a multi-dimensional array with 6 "columns" holding computer information.

Would this 'if' take longer to search the object/array if the object also held more details about the computer (ram, harddrive, etc) and had more "columns"? Or does the dot notation prevent that?

Comment: Until there's a truly huge number of properties, property access is efficient and not really a function of how many there are.

Comment: Not sure what you're doing there, `$.inArray` expects 2 arguments. Also it would be easier if you could post the JSON itself, not the PHP code that generated it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Property lookup is slower the more you go down the prototype chain. In your case, you are not looping through objects, but rather through array indexes. So once you have the object reference cached, retrieving properties should not be slow.

Avoid looping through object properties when you are already a long way down the chain:

`for( property in object.property1.property2.property3[i] )`
as this would be indeed slower.

Comment: What do property lookups have to do with the scope chain?

Comment: Just to be clear, the number of properties in the array doesn't affect the time spent?